# Flash AS3 animation not running in IE9

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer-9

I've got five Flash animations, that use AS3 computeSpectrum to create video animations for some of my songs.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari just fine. Tested in IE7 and IE8 just fine. Tested in IE9, the flash player opens, but the music doesn't play, and the animations don't even start. This ONLY occurs in IE9.

Web page here: http://seanmurphy.co.cc/index4.html

The animations are under the music tab (bottom tab, main screen).

Does anyone have a line on what the heck is going on? I've made sure the Flash player is up-to-date (like I said, actually uninstalled IE9, back to IE8 and worked fine). I've made sure the linked mp3 files are in both the root folder and the attached audio folder (just in case). I've researched this all over, but no one seems to have this same problem.

Flash AS3 code below:

```
var url:String = "SubwayGirl.mp3";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
import flash.filters.*;
import fl.motion.Color;
var myBlur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();
myBlur.quality = 10;
myBlur.blurX = 0;
myBlur.blurY = 6;
var s:Sound = new Sound();
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
s.load(request);
var song:SoundChannel = s.play();
song.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var gr:Sprite = new Sprite();
gr.x = 150;
gr.y = 575;
addChild(gr);
var time:Timer = new Timer(.0001);
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
time.start();
function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    //event.target.play();
};
function randomNumber(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}

function soundCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    time.stop();
};
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {  
    SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(ba, true);
    var i:int;
    gr.graphics.clear();
    gr.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xffffff);
    myBlur.blurX = randomNumber(1, 5);
    myBlur.blurY = randomNumber(1, 25);
    myBlur.quality = randomNumber(1, 100);
gr.filters = [myBlur];
gr.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
gr.graphics.moveTo(10, 5);
var w:uint = 20;
for (i=0; i<500; i+=w) {
    var t:Number = ba.readFloat();
    var n:Number = (t * 100);
    gr.graphics.drawCircle(w, -i, -n);
    var yy = i * (t+210);
    var place = yy.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while(place.length < 6) {
        place = place+"0";
    }
    place = "0x" + place;
    var myColor:ColorTransform = gr.transform.colorTransform;
    myColor.color = 0xC941D0;
    gr.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
};
};
```

Anyone with a hint on this? I've spent hours researching this with no resolution.

Any further info needed will be ASAPed over. Thanks.

EDIT: Okay, here's the scoop: I've got Flash animations playing at seanmurphy.co.cc/soundTest1.html in IE9. That is, they play if the browser cache is emptied, and you load the page once. If you reload the page, or go back to the page after visiting another page, the animations and music WON'T play, until you empty the cache again.

As well, I've copied the Flash object and embed codes over to a temporary index file at seanmurphy.co.cc/index6.html, but they won't play even with the browser cache emptied.

As you might think, this is driving me friggin' nuts! Does ANYONE have an explanation for the idiotic crap that IE is pulling here? I'd really really like to put this thing to bed. Thanks!

Comment: The site works fine in my IE9..

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the Security Sandbox violation:

```
SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: 
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum: http://seanmurphy.co.cc/audio/IndianSummer-amped.swf 
cannot access http://seanmurphy.co.cc/audio/SubwayGirl.swf. 
This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
    at flash.media::SoundMixer$/computeSpectrum()
    at IndianSummer_fla::MainTimeline/timerHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: Hi Strah, I kinda surmised it was some security breach or another... if I were more an AS3 guy (instead of JQuery and JS), I'd jump right in and heave it out. As it is, I'll have to devote time to it when possible, as my actionscripting in AS3 is pretty much cut, paste and haggle with. Thanks man!